# Strong separation of symmetric rank $1$ matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, functional-analysis, hahn-banach-theorem

Let $V$ be the inner product space of $n \times n$ symmetric matrices where the inner product is given by $\langle A, B \rangle = trace(AB)$ and let $A, B \in V$ be such that they have eigenvalue $1$ and rank $1$, does there then always exist a matrix $C \in V$ such that $trace(AC)=0, trace(BC)\neq 0$? Or is there a counterexample?

Note: it suffices to only prove the case where $A=diag(1,0,\dots 0)$. If $trace(AB)=0$ everything’s okay of course (take $C=B$).

Motivation: I’d want this to be true as this “strong separation” property of matrices as described above by the space $V$ is a condition I’d want to be true to apply some theorem I’ve proven.

Comment: If $A$ is a matrix, what does $A=(1,0,..,0)$ mean?

Comment: Oh I meant $A=diag(1,0,\dots,0)$ there, I’ll edit it now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $A$ and $B$ with rank $1$ such that $A = u u^T$ and $B = v v^T$ for som $u,v$. For arbitrary $C = w w^T$ you have $Trace(AC) = trace(u u^T w w^T ) = u^t w \,\, trace(u w^T )$ and $Trace(BC) = v^T w \,\, trace(v w^T )$. Therefore any $w$ that is orthogonal to $u$ but not to $v$ will suffice. Of course if $u$ and $v$ are parallel this does not exist.

Comment: Ah but $u,v$ being parallel can not happen if $A,B$ both have only $1$ eigenvalue $1$ not?

Comment: No. You could have $u = v$ or $u = -v$. In this case they are parallel and the eigenvalues of $A$ and $B$ would be the same.

Comment: Cool. I think your idea works, but wasn’t it the case that the matrices could be decomposed as a product of two possibly different vectors? So no necessarily $A=uu^{\top}$ but more so $A=xy^{\top}$?

Comment: Errrr yes, you are right. My answer provides a counter example in the case where $A$ and $B$ are as stated (I have edited it for clarity). The general claim is still false.

Comment: If this works, please accept the answer :)